# How do I get my Samsung Galaxy S3 into development mode for a basic hello world app?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have a galaxy s3, model sph-l710, android version 4.3.  I'd like to get it into development mode so I can get things running on android studio.  I'll be happy if this gets closed a duplicate, but I really can't find the help I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the settings menu on your GS5.
2. Scroll down to the "System section and tap "About Device."
3. Now scroll down to "Build number." Tap the "Build number" section seven times. (You'll see a warning that you're about to unlock developer options.)
4. Now back out to the main settings menu, and you'll see "Developer options" listed.